# is therea way/hack to replace ajax text with image

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I have a HTML webpage who display some sensor readings using ajax every second, and I want to replace the text with an image (except base64 because is too big).

So my code who send the ajax(no cache) is this:

```
print("<analog>");
if (h <= 50) {
print("sunny");
} else if (h >= 75) {
print("storm");
} else {
print("cloud");
}
print("</analog>");
```

...so will print on webpage "sunny", "cloud" or "storm" in analog tags, but if I view the page source only write

```
<analog> </analog>
```

and I cant convert the text with image, like "sunny" with `<img src... sunny.gif>`

Is there a way to force ajax text replaced by an image?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code shall output something like this:

```
<analog value="sunny" />
<analog value="storm" />
<analog value="cloud" />
```

then in CSS you will be able to style it as:

```
analog { display:block; }
analog[value="sunny"] { background-image:url(...sunny.gif); }
analog[value="storm"] { background-image:url(...storm.gif); }
analog[value="cloud"] { background-image:url(...cloud.gif); }
```

Comment: thank you sir for your fast response. my java code to read analog values is:  var num_an = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('analog').length;
       for (count = 0; count < num_an; count++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("analog")[count].innerHTML =
         this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('analog')[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue;   so I cannot put nothing like value... can I change this?